# PyCrypto AES encryption not working as expected

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

I am creating a Python function to perform counter mode encryption using the [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) module. I am aware of the builtin, but want to implement it myself.

I'm trying  [Test Vector #1 from RFC 3686](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3686#section-6), and have the correct Counter Block and the correct Key in ASCII form. But when I encrypt the Counter Block using the Key, I don't get the expected Key Stream.

The relevant parts of my code:

```
cipher = AES.new(key)
ctr_block = iv + nonce + ctr
key_stream = base64.b64decode(cipher.encrypt(ctr_block))
```

I can provide more code if needed, but I'm not sure how because `ctr_block` and `key` have many question mark characters when I print them.

Why am I not getting the expected answer? It seems like everything should go right. Perhaps I made some mistake with the encoding of the string.

**Edit**

Self-contained code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def hex_to_str(hex_str):
    return str(bytearray([int(n, 16) for n in hex_str.split()]))

key = hex_to_str("AE 68 52 F8 12 10 67 CC 4B F7 A5 76 55 77 F3 9E")
iv = hex_to_str("00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00")
nonce = hex_to_str("00 00 00 30")
ctr = hex_to_str("00 00 00 01")

cipher = AES.new(key)
ctr_block = iv + nonce + ctr
key_stream = base64.b64decode(cipher.encrypt(ctr_block))

print "".join([hex(ord(char)) for char in key_stream])
# 0xd90xda0x72
```

Comment: To provide an example that can be tested you need at least to show how you made `key`, `iv`, `nonce` and `ctr`.

Comment: An example would be [Roland Smith's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15736125/805556).

Comment: No, it's not a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example.

Comment: I have updated my answer with code that is described by the first two adjectives but probably not the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct CTR block order is `nonce + iv + ctr`. Second, that `base64.b64decode` call is wrong: `cipher.encrypt` produces a decoded string. After these two fixes your code prints `0xb70x600x330x280xdb0xc20x930x1b0x410xe0x160xc80x60x7e0x620xdf` which seems to be a correct key stream.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I got the incorrect `b64encode` part from a [blog post](http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2009/aes-encryption-python-using-pycrypto/) which I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

First, use byte strings:

```
In [14]: keystring = "AE 68 52 F8 12 10 67 CC 4B F7 A5 76 55 77 F3 9E"

In [15]: keystring.replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
Out[15]: '\xaehR\xf8\x12\x10g\xccK\xf7\xa5vUw\xf3\x9e'
```

Second, you shouldn't use base64.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Using your code I still get the wrong answer. However, I just discovered something: My keystream is only _three characters long_.

Comment: Thanks for the function, but my code still doesn't work. Please see my edit.